# how to check every pandas series value is integer and count?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to check if every value in a pandas series is integer and count?
I found a way to use to transform it to a list

```
pd.xxx.tolist()
```

and check every value with

`1.1.is_integer()
False`

to check for it .
I'm just thinking if there is more tricky way to check it using pandas or numpy?

Env:python3.6

Comment: Are you looking to check the dtypes AND count the number of elements in the series?

Comment: What does 'and count' mean?  Please show some reproducible code including data.  This will help others in assisting you.  What is 1.1?

Comment: if the data looks like this `[1,1.1,2,3,2.3]`,I want to count the integer in it ,in this case ,there are 3 integer  in this list .I'm wondering using pandas to process it

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.Series` possesses an attribute `dtype`. Accessing this directly will tell you if the entire `Series` contains integers:

```
s = pandas.Series([0,1])
print(s.dtype)
```

Note: if your `pandas.Series` contains different data types `s.dtype` will default to `object`.